# /src/DB/sqlite3.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Tags: c++, c++11, dll, sqlite

I am trying to include a sqlite3 in my cpp project but while compilation it gives below error:

> g++ -c -std=c++11 -g src/Main.cpp  -I"C:/Mycode/src/DB"
> -L"C:/Mycode/src/DB" -lsqlite3
>
> g++ -g -o Main.exe Main.o Data.o SqliteApi.o -lws2_32
> -L"C:/Mycode/src/DB" -lsqlite3
>
> C:/Mycode/src/DB/sqlite3.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make: ***[Mycode.exe] Error 1

I feel during final linking time it gives error.
I am using my own make file for compilation, below is the make command I am using:

```
DB_DIR="C:/Mycode/src/DB"

clean:
    rm Main.o Main.exe
  
Main.exe: Main.o Data.o SqliteApi.o 
    g++ -g -o Main.exe Main.o Data.o SqliteApi.o -lws2_32 -L${DB_DIR} -lsqlite3 

Main.o: src/Main.cpp
    g++ -c -std=c++11 -g src/Main.cpp -I${DB_DIR} -lsqlite3
    
Data.o: src/Data.cpp
    g++ -c -std=c++11 -g src/Data.cpp
    
SqliteApi.o: src/SqliteApi.cpp
    g++ -c -std=c++11 -g src/SqliteApi.cpp
```

I have googled but I couldn't find any solution or suggestion for this error.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How did you compile the SQLite library?

Comment: I have not compiled but I am linking sqlite3 dll.
Do i need to compile separately ?

Answer (score 0):

The [recommended way of using the SQLite library](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html) is to compile the amalgamation source file directly into your program:

```
Main.exe: Main.o Data.o SqliteApi.o 
    g++ -g -o Main.exe Main.o Data.o SqliteApi.o sqlite3.o -lws2_32

sqlite3.o: src/sqlite3.c
    gcc -c ... src/sqlite3.c
```

Comment: :I was about to post my comment with exact same thing as after compilation it got fixed.
Anyway Thanks a lot for prompt suggestion.